# 'this' undefined in renderMenuItemChildren

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using [react-bootstrap-typeahead asynchronous searching](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#asynchronous-searching). In the `renderMenuItemChildren` method I want to call another method `handleSubmit` to fetch details of the selected item.

`this` is undefined inside `renderMenuItemChildren` and I'm not able to call the method. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I'm still learning react so there might be a silly mistake I'm not able to identify.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTitle: '',
      defaultUrl: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=arrival'
    };
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.fetchApiData = this.fetchApiData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchApiData(this.state.defaultUrl);
  }

  fetchApiData(url){
    fetch(url) 
     .then((result) => {
        return result.json()
     })
     .then((json) => {
        if(json.Response === "True"){
          this.setState({
            title: json.Title,
            year: json.Year,
            released: json.Released,
            runtime: json.Runtime,
            genreList: json.Genre,
            actors: json.Actors,
            plot: json.Plot,
            poster_url: json.Poster,
            rating: json.imdbRating,
            boxOffice: json.BoxOffice,
            votes: json.imdbVotes,
            response: json.Response
        });
      }
      else {
        this.setState({
          response: json.Response,
          error: json.Error
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(query){
    if (!query) {
      return;
    }
    this.fetchApiData(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${query}`);
  }

  handleSearch(query) {
    if (!query) {
      return;
    }

    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${query}`)
      .then((result) => {
        return result.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        //console.log(json.Search);
        this.setState({
          options: json.Search
        })
      });
  }

  renderMenuItemChildren(option, props, index) {
    return (
      <div key={option.imdbID} onClick={() => 
        this.handleSubmit.bind(option.Title)}>
        <span>{option.Title}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          <div className="App-header col-xs-12">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5">
                <h1><a href="http://www.omdbapi.com/" className="omdb-link" title="The Open Movie Database">OMDb</a></h1>
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7">

                <AsyncTypeahead
                  ref="typeahead"
                  {...this.state}
                  labelKey="Title"
                  onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                  options={this.state.options}
                  placeholder='Search Title'
                  className="search-input-box"
                  renderMenuItemChildren={this.renderMenuItemChildren}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <SearchBody data={this.state} />
      </div>
    </div>
    );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need => function here. You can use below code to pass the title value back to handleSubmit()

```
renderMenuItemChildren(option, props, index) {
  return (
    <div key={option.imdbID} onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this, option.Title)}>
      <span>{option.Title}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Though this didn't entirely work, I had to bind renderMenuItemChildren as suggested by @T.J. Crowder too

Comment: Ideally speaking, you don't need to bind it at both the location i.e. while calling and in constructor. Any one of these should be sufficient. But Anyways, I am glad the solution somewhat helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the function `renderMenuItemChildren` in the constructor as well:

add this:

```
this.renderMenuItemChildren = this.renderMenuItemChildren.bind(this);
```

Here is a nice little blog post with several ways to this: [Blog Post](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)
That said I prefer lodash's bindAll:

`_.bindAll(this, function1, function2, function3)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do what you've done for your other methods (`handleSearch`, `handleSubmit`, etc.) in the constructor:

```
this.renderMenuItemChildren = this.renderMenuItemChildren.bind(this);
```

(Or several other ways, but this is the way you're using for your other methods, so...)

Comment: thank you, renderMenuItemChildren is a method of AsyncTypeahead so I thought I might not need to bind it.

Answer (score 1):

While `renderMenuItemChildren.bind(this)` in constructor will definitely works, es6 classes also allows you to use **arrow function expressions** as class methods. This will automatically bind `this` (or, in other words, context) to the method, reduces amount of boilerplate code, and make your components easier to read.

So your code could be something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTitle: '',
      defaultUrl: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=arrival'
    };
  }

  // etc...

  renderMenuItemChildren = () => {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```